# What does <Object> in Map<Object> mean?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I don't know what this code is

```
Map<Object>
```

What do they call these on java?

Can you tell me what does the code means? Is this casting? Can you direct me to an article leading to more examples and explanation of the said code?

Comment: That example is syntactically and semantically wrong. 

A map <code>Map<V,K></code> Maps types of type V to type K. Read the Java API: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

You MIGHT be interested in generic classes in java, how about this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 7):

It's a declaration of a *generic* type. See [this doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for more info.